# Normalize data based on country population

Tags: statistics

I'm working on an Applied Statistics project on COVID-19 data in Excel and I got stuck. I have the number of new cases during a period of time for two countries with different populations and I would like to normalize those numbers based on each country's population. How is it possible to achieve that?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi! The answer to the math part of this question is: divide each case number by the country's population.  The rest of the question (how to get the country populations? how to do this quickly in Excel?) isn't really about math, so you should probably ask elsewhere

Comment: @MatthewLeingang The math aspect is the one that interested me most, because that's where I got stuck. Thank you!